# Reading content length of website

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get the content length of the web page. example http://www.google.com.

I am using c# and below is the code I used and does not give me correct length or does it. Can some one validate please.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com.au");
request.Method = "GET";
var myResponse = request.GetResponse();
var responseLength = myResponse.ContentLength;

using (var sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    var result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    myResponse.Close();
}
```

responseLength is -1 allways but result.Length has some value, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, ContentLength is not reliable, it requires that the server provide a value in a response header which is not always the case (or even possible for dynamic content given that the header must be sent first)

Answer (score 2):

> responseLength is -1 allways but result.Length has some value, is that correct?

Well it may be for some web sites (or some responses in some web sites) - in other cases, you'll see a non-negative value for `responseLength`. All you're doing is fetching the optional `Content-Length` HTTP header, basically... it's up to the server whether it supplies that or not.

Note that the response length, if provided, will be in bytes - whereas `result.Length` is in UTF-16 code units. If you want the content length in *bytes*, you should be reading the binary data from the stream directly rather than creating a `StreamReader` and reading it as text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to DownloadString and then check the length.

`Console.WriteLine(new WebClient().DownloadString("https://google.com/").Length);`